# Longest common subsequence (Why does this recursive solution not work?)

Tags: javascript, recursion

Trying to write a similar recursive solution to the one described on: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-subsequence/ but it does not work. It outputs one. Anyone have an idea of why?

```
LCS_seq_req = (str1, str2) => {

  m=str1.length;
  n=str2.length;

  str1_cut = str1.slice(0, m-1)
  str2_cut = str2.slice(0, n-1)

  if (m===0 || n===0) {
    return 0
  }
  else if (str1.slice(m-1, m) === str2.slice(n-1, n) ) {
    return  LCS_seq_req(str1_cut, str2_cut) + 1
  } else {
    res_1 = LCS_seq_req(str1_cut, str2)
    res_2 = LCS_seq_req(str1,str2_cut)

    return Math.max(res_1, res_2)
  }

}
LCS_seq_req("AGGTAB", "GXTXAYB")
```

Comment: As an aside, are you aware that `.slice(-1)` gives you the last character of a string, and `.slice(0, -1)` gives you all but the last character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, unlike (say) Python, assigning to a variable inside a function does *not* implicitly declare it as a local variable. Instead, you need to *explicitly* declare it using the `var` keyword; otherwise you get a global variable.

More specifically, your problem is that this line:

```
    res_1 = LCS_seq_req(str1_cut, str2)
```

has the side-effect of mutating the global variable `str2_cut`, causing this line:

```
    res_2 = LCS_seq_req(str1,str2_cut)
```

to compute the wrong value. If you add `var` in the right places, you'll get the right answer.

---

Incidentally, Eric Lippert has written a blog post, https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, which gives very good advice for how to debug this sort of problem on your own.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, there are no arrays in the OP's code, they're using the *string* `.slice()` method. But still, `str1[m-1]` would be a better option with strings too - even ignoring performance it is easier to read.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Whoops, thanks for pointing that out! I can't find any documentation on whether string `slice` should create a copy -- implementations probably get to make a space/time tradeoff -- so I've just dropped that part of my answer.

Comment: MDN says it "returns it as a new string". But even if there were some fancy optimization behind the scenes to somehow share a section of memory that would still have *some* overhead. And `[]` avoids the overhead of a function call. Anyway, the local/global variable thing is the problem, well spotted.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Since JavaScript strings are immutable, I don't think it requires any fancy optimizations to use the same underlying array for strings returned by `substr`/`substring`/`slice`. I know that the Java analogues have had both implementations: the Oracle JDK used to reuse the underlying array until a few years ago, when they decided that the risk of failing to garbage-collect a long string due to a small surviving substring was a bigger problem than the risk of copying too much too often.

Answer (score -1):

I looked at the [Naive recursive Python implementation of LCS problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-subsequence/) you give and converted Python code into JS code. Hope it will help.

```
LCS_seq_req = (str1, str2, m, n) => {
  if(m == 0 || n == 0)
    return 0;
  else if(str1.charAt(m-1) === str2.charAt(n-1))
    return 1 + LCS_seq_req(str1, str2, m-1, n-1);
  else
    return Math.max(LCS_seq_req(str1, str2, m, n-1), LCS_seq_req(str1, str2, m-1, n));
}

var X = "AGGTAB";
var Y = "GXTXAYB";
console.log(LCS_seq_req(X , Y, X.length, Y.length));  //6
```

Comment: This is similar to the OP's code. Why doesn't theirs work? What are `str1_cut` and `str2_cut` doing in this version?

Comment: @nnnnnn Aha I removed unnecessary lines.